# Python, изменить аттрибут класса, ссылающийся на атррибут другого класса

Tags: python, классы, атрибуты

У меня есть код:

```
class Parameters:
    PARAM1 = 'param1'
    PARAM2 = 'param2'


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.param_dict = {'path1': Parameters.PARAM1, 'path2': Parameters.PARAM2}


a = Test()
print(a.param_dict['path1'])

Parameters.PARAM1 = 'new_param1'
print(a.param_dict['path1'])
```

В нем два класса, единственный атрибут второго класса ссылается на атрибуты первого. Вывод данного кода следующий:

```
param1
param1
```

Я могу как то повлиять на атрибут класса `Test`, изменив атрибут класса `Parameters` после инициализации объекта `Test`? То есть что бы вывод был:

```
param1
new_param1
```

Comment: Но зачем? Экземпляр класса имеет свои собственные копии атрибутов класса, они теряют связь с самим классом. И это правильно, иначе зачем вообще нужны экземпляры класса, если у них будут все те же значения, что у самого класса? Извернуться то можно как-то, но ЗАЧЕМ? Можно хранить в классе список экземпляров класса, например, много чего можно придумать. Особенно через метаклассы.